# Определить лежит ли точка на прямой

Tags: алгоритм, canvas

Как в canvas определить лежит ли точка на прямой. Уточню - прямая толстая, то есть по сути это наклонный прямоугольник.

Пробовал по формуле взятой из [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/55734/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9) и с небольшой погрешностью.

В случае с наклонными линиями все работает. Но если линия горизонтальная или вертикальная, то вычисление по данной формуле равно `Infinity`. А если прямых несколько, то соответственно не определить, на которой из них располагается точка

Подскажите пожалуйста алгоритм.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проще всего воспользоваться псевдоскалярным произведением.

Если линия задана двумя точками `A(x1, y1)` и `B(x2, y2)`, и третья точка `C(x, y)`, то надо подсчитать величину

```
dx1 = x2 - x1;
dy1 = y2 - y1;

dx = x - x1;
dy = y - y1;

S = dx1 * dy - dx * dy1;
```

Эта величина равна удвоенной (ориентированной) площади треугольника, составленного тремя точками, и равна нулю если три точки лежат на одной прямой.

Работает, очевидно, вне зависимости от вертикальности/горизонтальности прямых.

---

Вы можете вычислять расстояние от точки `C` до прямой `AB`, поделив на длину отрезка `AB`. Величины `dx1`, `dy1` и `|AB| = Math.Sqrt(dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1)` можно подсчитать заранее.

Если ваша прямая имеет заданную толщину `d`, можно сравнивать с ней:

```
ab = Math.Sqrt(dx1 * dx1 + dy1 * dy1);

h = S / ab;
if (Math.Abs(h) < d/2)
{
    // точка лежит на толстой прямой
```

Comment: Я уже пробовал данный метод - ссылка на решение в описании. У меня линия толстая, и по сути являет собой наклонный прямоугольник.

А если использую погрешность, то и возникает проблемы с вертикальными/горизонтальными линиями

Comment: @DOC_tr: Это не тот метод, на который вы ссылаетесь. У этого метода никогда не получается бесконечность.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Бесконечности нет. И установив погрешность в `1000` я смог отлавливать нажатие на нужную прямую. Спасибо

Comment: @DOC_tr: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @DOC_tr: Вы можете вычислять расстояние от точки до прямой. Дописал в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Логически можно найти так: если длина линии равна сумме расстояний от двух краев линии до точки, то точка лежит в линии. Пользуйтесь )

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/719381)

Comment: @Ulanbek Во-первых, такой метод вычислительно более затратен, чем векторное произведение, поскольку нужно вычислять квадратный корень, во-вторых, он непригоден для точек, лежащих на прямой за границами сегмента.