# Как написать функцию проверки на существование треугольника? c++

Tags: c++

Как написать функцию проверки на существование треугольника? Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

double Triangle(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3)
{
    double a, b, c;
    // Находим длину отрезков треугольника по его координатам
    a = sqrt(pow(x2 - x1, 2) + pow(y2 - y1, 2));
    b = sqrt(pow(x3 - x1, 2) + pow(y3 - y1, 2));
    c = sqrt(pow(x3 - x2, 2) + pow(y3 - y2, 2));
    // Находим площадь по формуле Герона
    double p = (a + b + c) / 2;
    double S = sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c));
    return S;
}




void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Название задачи: ";
    cout << "Треугольник задан координатами своих вершин. Составить программу для вычисления его площади.";
    cout << endl;

    double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Введите координаты: ";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "\nx1 = "; cin >> x1;
    cout << "\ny1 = "; cin >> y1;
    cout << "\nx2 = "; cin >> x2;
    cout << "\ny2 = "; cin >> y2;
    cout << "\nx3 = "; cin >> x3;
    cout << "\ny3 = "; cin >> y3;

    double R = Triangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);

    cout << "\nПлощадь треугольника равна: " << R;
    cout << endl;



    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: И что вы получите, если он **не** существует? кстати, `x*x` проще и быстрее `pow(x,2)`, но вопрос не в этом...

Comment: @Harry если даже он не существует то должно хотя бы вывести сообщение "Треугольник не существует"

Comment: А чем не устраивает сообщение об ошибке вычисления квадратного корня из отрицательного числа? отличный маркер, что треугольник не существует...

Comment: @user353174, Треугольник - это фигура из трех точек, не принадлежащих одной прямой. Значит, подойдет решение [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/55738/192978).

Comment: интересно что означает длина отрезков треугольников... и с чего вы взяли, что  эти координаты должны образовать прямоугольный треугольник?..

Comment: Я спросил не что программа **должна** делать, а что именно будет делать ваш код. А он будет пытаться вычислить квадратный корень из отрицательного числа... Такой разжеванный намек понятен?