# Как определить, лежат ли две точки на одной прямой?

Tags: python, математика, геометрия

Определите лежат ли две точки (x1,y1) и (x2,y2) на одной прямой.

Comment: Вы это серьезно?!

Comment: @Harry А почему нет? Вот аналогичный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/55734/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как определить, лежат ли точки на одной прямой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/55734/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9)

Comment: @Konstantin_SH А вы не видите разницу между "хотя бы **три** точки" и "две точки"?...

Comment: @Harry Я вижу. Но в ответе на тот вопрос и уравнение прямой, проходящей через две точки тоже есть.

Answer (score 4):

```py
def func(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    return True
```

Answer (score 4):

*"Вокруг стеклянного плафона под потолком обессиленно мотались три мухи — должно быть, первые мухи в этом году. Время от времени они вдруг принимались остервенело кидаться из стороны в сторону, и спросонок мне пришла в голову гениальная идея, что мухи, наверное, стараются выскочить из плоскости, через них проходящей, и я посочувствовал этому безнадёжному занятию. Две мухи сели на плафон, а третья исчезла, и тогда я окончательно проснулся."* (с) Стругацкие, "Понедельник начинается в субботу"

Простите уж за обильное цитирование Стругацких, но две точки **всегда** лежат на одной прямой, *однозначно ее определяя*. Как три - на одной плоскости.

Единственный *частный случай* - при совпадении точек таких прямых бесконечно много...

Comment: если точки совпадают они все равно лежат на одной прямой :) на счет единственного частного случая - нет, пример геометрии на сфере и 2х точек на 2х полюсах ;-)

Comment: @Zhihar А я что написал? Только таких прямых бесконечно много. Мы же работаем в рамках Евклидовой геометрии?

Answer (score 3):

лежат, одна из аксиом геометрии - через 2 точки всегда можно провести прямую :)

если же вам дана прямая в виде уравнения `ax + by + c = 0`, то в случае, если точки лежат на прямой, то подставив координаты каждой точки в уравнение вы должны получить тождество `0 = 0`